# can i get specified ERC20 token holders details?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, dapps

can i get specified ERC20 token holders details,example token holder address,how many token holding that address like this details

Answer (score 1):

You have to subscribe to all `Transfer` events and store the source and destination address. That will get you a list of all token holders. After that you can use `balanceOf()` to query the token balance of each account.